# Doctrine query only returning one row?

Tags: doctrine

I'm new to Doctrine but somewhat familiar with SQL.  I have a very simple schema with Users and Challenges.  Each Challenge has a "challenger id" and a "opponent id" which are foreign keys into the User table.  I want to print a list of all challenges, with the output being the names from the User table.  Here is my Doctrine query;

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('u1.name challenger, u2.name opponent')
        ->from('Challenge c')
            ->leftJoin('c.Challenger u1')
            ->leftJoin('c.Opponent u2');
```

The problem is that this only returns one row.  I've used the getSqlQuery() command to look at the generated SQL which ends up being:

```
SELECT u.name AS u__0, u2.name AS u2__1 FROM challenge c 
LEFT JOIN user u ON c.challenger_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON c.opponent_id = u2.id
```

When run in a 3rd party SQL client this query retrieves all of the rows as expected.  Any idea how I can get all of the rows from Doctrine?  I'm using `$q->execute()` which I understand should work for multiple rows.

Thanks.

Comment: try $q->count() and see how many rows its saying it gets. Also, use the <app name>_dev.php to access the query. Once it has run, click the database and see what query it is actually running. I'm not sure this would be any different from what is returned by the getSqlQuery() though.

Comment: Thanks.  $q->count() exposed that the query is returning the right number of results and that I need to read up on the correct use of DoctrineCollection object.  That's beyond the scope of my question here so I'll close it out.

Comment: Awesome, you are welcome to mark my comment as a "great" comment ;)

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked by chaning the hydration mode:

```
$result = $query->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
```

Set result set then returns an array instead of objects.

Comment: I did this, and it worked, but all fields became prefixed with the alias of the first table I selected..

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue and in my case the problem was that my query didn't select any field from the FROM table. Example:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select(
                'ghl.id as id,
                ghl.patbase_id as patbase_id,
                ghl.publication_no as publication_no,
                ghl.priority_no as priority_no
                '
            )
            ->from('GridHitListContents ghlc')
            ->leftJoin('ghlc.GridHitList ghl')
```

As you can see there is no selected field from the GridHitListContents table.
with a $query->count() I got 2000ish results, but with $query->fetchArray() only the first one.
When I added

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select(
                'ghlc.id,
                ghl.id as id,
                ...
                '
            )
            ->from('GridHitListContents ghlc')
            ->leftJoin('ghlc.GridHitList ghl')
```

I got back all my results.

Comment: This solved my issue, too.

I was running a `table.*` in my SQL, but it was combining the results, and returning a single row. Including a `table.id AS table_id, table.*` as the select returned each row needed.

Answer (score 1):

`$query->fetchOne()` work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `$result = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY)`